# select all data from a table + totalSum from this table

Tags: android, android-room

I have 2 queries

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM basket_items")
LiveData<List<BasketItem>> getAll();

@Query("SELECT SUM(count*amount) FROM basket_items")
LiveData<Double> totalSum();
```

How can I select this data by one query?

I created model

```
public class BasketItemWithTotal {
    private List<BasketItem> basketItems;
    private Double total;
}
```

and created query:

```
@Query("SELECT *, SUM(count*amount) as total FROM basket_items")
LiveData<BasketItemWithTotal> getAllWithTotal();
```

but it's not working

Comment: Either ask db using 2 queries or calculate total from items on java side

Comment: if I use 2 query I do not know when all data is loadded. I need load all data end send it to server. calculate total from items on java side - I think this is a more difficult process than getting them out of the database. I use 2 query when show data on view. but in this case I nedd load data and send as soon as I get it

Comment: yeah, iterate items and sum product of count and amout is very difficult ... in C# it could looks like `var total = theArray.Sum(i=>i.count*i.amount);`

Comment: I already have this data, but I need to pass them in a new activity. Now I pass them to putSerializable and get in new activity. But I think it not good, and I want load it from db in new activity instead pass in bundle

Comment: I can use lambda in java(android) too. but this way heavier than  select from db

Comment: There is no way to combine them in one query, for your problem I think you should use store procedure. You can create a store procedure with your first select and return SUM(count*amount) or assign it into out variable